# How to read website's data and post to another website's database like mysql

Tags: php, curl, mysqli, https, http-headers

the following code i have 3 functions, when i run my example2 website it's being got into my website like after providing the username and password.The example2 is working fine. But in the example1 website when i am executing this program, its being got into my previous pages, its supposed to no impact of username and password. In both cases, i am getting the username & password plus other data as $data variable by running the httpfox software. i reckon, in example2 this software is showing all information like 'username=YYYYY&password=YYYYYYYYY&remember=yes&submit=Login&action=do_login&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hackforums.net%2Findex.php&my_post_key=876890b33b8b9260ba3acfc1998b1594' but in example1, its only showing, 'username=XXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
Can anyone know the answer? it would be great help!

Another question is it's not working any 'https' website. Do you know how to do that. Thanks a lot!

```html
<html>
<body>
 
<?php 
       
       
 login("http://www.example1.com:9080/mrportal/loginaction", "username=XXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") ; 
echo grabpage("http://www.example1.com:9080/mrportal/");

login("http://www.example2.net/member.php", "username=YYYYY&password=YYYYYYYYY&remember=yes&submit=Login&action=do_login&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hackforums.net%2Findex.php&my_post_key=876890b33b8b9260ba3acfc1998b1594") ; 
echo grabpage("http://www.example2.net)

 function login($url, $data)
 {
   $fp = fopen("cookie.txt","w");
   fclose($fp);
   $login = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
   curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
   curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,40000);
   curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   ob_start();
   return curl_exec($login);
   ob_end_clean();
   curl_close($login);
   unset($login);  
 }
 
 function grabpage($site)
 {
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,400);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $site);
   ob_start();
   return curl_exec($ch);
   ob_end_clean();
   curl_close($ch);
  }
 
 
    function post_data($site, $data)
 {
   
   $datapost = curl_init();
   $headers = array("Expect:");
   curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_URL, $site);
   curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,40000);  
   curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
   ob_start();
   return curl_exec($datapost);
   ob_end_clean();
   curl_close($datapost);
   unset($datapost);  
 }
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

in your code to skip ssl verification for https addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried many ways after putting your line but nothing changed. when i try echo grabpage("http://www.example1.com:9080/mrportal/")

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried many ways after putting your line but nothing changed. when i try like echo grabpage("http://www.example1.com:9080/mrportal/") then the previous page appears. if i  try echo grabpage("http://www.example1.com:9080/mrportal") then empty page appears, if try echo grabpage("http://www.example1.com:9080/mrportal/loginaction") then saying error '404 server error the requested url was not found'